# Automatize as.factor function on some variables via a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I was struggling with the iteration of `as.factor()` function on the following list of variables.

```
d$block <- as.factor(d$block)
d$CR <- as.factor(d$CR)
d$T1.ACC <- as.factor(d$T1.ACC)
d$T1.correct <- as.factor(d$T1.correct)
d$T1.response <- as.factor(d$T1.response)
```

I was wondering how to create some code lines with either a for loop to iterate the as.factor function on such a list. Actually I used the following code

```
d %>% 
  dplyr::select(
    block, CR, T1.ACC, T1.correct, T1.response) %>% 
  lapply(., as.factor) %>% 
  lapply(., is.factor)
```

But when going to verify variable singularly, that doesn't seem to work.

```
> is.factor(d$block)
[1] FALSE
```

Which one could be the problem? How it would be possible to code a good for loop? Thanks for replying

Comment: You have to assign the result back to `d`. Actually, assign it to `d[]`. I have a truly wondrous explanation for why this is needed, but this comment is too short to contain it

Comment: Could you please be clearer when you refer to d[] assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`'s `across` function:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- d %>%
  mutate(across(c(block, CR, T1.ACC, T1.correct, T1.response), as.factor))
```

If you really want to use a `for`-loop, you could use

```r
for (i in c("block", "CR", "T1.ACC", "T1.correct", "T1.response")){
  
  d[, i] <- as.factor(d[, i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works pretty well. It would be useful also to know how to code a for loop, if it could be indicated for this case.

Comment: Do you identify the columns by name or do they share a common and unique feature (for example: they are all character vectors) or they are all in columns 1 to 10?

Comment: Columns in my dataset are identified by name. It counts 20 variables actually. But my question was as far as the usage of for loop only onto those selected variables

Comment: @ag_stat I added a `for`-loop solution.